# Эффект Parallax WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, parallax

Пытаюсь сделать параллакс эффект, подобно этому

http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/

Перевернул интернет, но подходящего не нашел.

Задача состоит в том чтобы задний план (image) плавно менял свою позицию при движении мыши в противоположную сторону от нее.

Подскажите как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, считывать дельту движения мыши, вычислять коэффициэнт и сдвигать фон на его основе